# ASP TextBox loses ViewState

Tags: html, asp.net, textbox, .net-4.0

I have a simple TextBox:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbText" MaxLength="3" Width="80"  type="number">
</asp:TextBox>
```

When I add  `type="number"` the control loses its content after a post-back. I know there is no native support for this but it's a comfortable way to make sure only numbers can be entered.

How can I make the value remain in the TextBox and add the attribute `type="number"`?

Comment: Adding `type=number` does not disable the ViewSate. You must be doing something (wrong) elsewhere or setting a blank value to the TextBox on PostBack.

Comment: The problem is not the input 100% sure

Answer (score 0):

In your Page_Load() method you can **maintain** the value and **add** the attribute in `IsPostBack` check:

```
If(IsPostBack)
{
    tbText.Attributes.Add("type", "number");
    tbText.Attributes["value"]= tbText.Text;
}
```

**Explanation:**

- `IsPostBack` returns true which means a post-back is happened
- `tbText.Attributes.Add` adds attribute `type="number"` in textbox
- `tbText.Attributes["value"]` used to set the entered value in textbox

Answer (score -1):

Use TextMode

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbText" runat="server" TextMode="Number" />
```